# JComponent Titled Border

Tags: java, swing, components

I am making a simple swing application and I want to add some titled borders to my components. The border on both of my JScrollPanes work fine, but the JTextField and the JButtons don't. Allow me to share some screen shots.

[image: This is what I am expecting.]

[image: This is what I am getting.]

I just have simple code for this. i.e

```
TitledBorder border = new TitledBorder("Border");
convert.setBorder(border); //convert is the JButton
```

I don't see why it would not work for one thing, and work for the other. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Add the `JButton` (or ...) to a `JPanel` and `setBorder` on the panel instead, if I recall correctly, that should solve the problem.

Comment: `JComponent`: "we recommend that you put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`."

Answer (score 1):

A JTextField and JButton both use a Border already. So the titled border works but it changes the appearance of the component because you lose the default Border.

I also agree that normally you don't use a TitledBorder for an individual component but I suppose you could try to use a CompoundBorder to see if it looks any better:

```
CompoundBorder border = new CompoundBorder(titledBorder, button.getBorder());
button.setBorder( border );
```

but then the problem with the above approach is that you lose dynamic repainting of the border when you press/release the mouse on the button.